# Output var in html tag - meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

At the moment I am trying to learn developing meteor and now I got my first problem...

This is my function:

```
Template.berechnung.event({
'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var eins = parseInt(event.target.ersterWert.value);
    var zwei = parseInt(event.target.zweiterWert.value);
    var ergebnis = eins + zwei;
    console.log(ergebnis);
    return ergebnis;
}
```

});

And this is my html tag ...

```
<template name="berechnung">
<form>
    <div>
        Erster Wert:
        <input type="text" name="ersterWert">
        <input type="text" name="zweiterWert">
        <input type="submit" value="Rechnung starten">
        <ul>{{ergebnis}}</ul>
        <div {{ergebnis.value}}></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to put the var "ergebnis" as an output in the html div or ul tag...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to read Meteor's official tutorial before you start writing your apps: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/forms-and-events

And reading Meteor docs can also help: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers

You can simply achieve it by using jQuery or the Meteor way is to use [ReactiveVar](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg) and helpers:

Add `reactive-var` package into your app:

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

Then you have to define local template reactive variable, helper and your event:

```
Template.berechnung.onCreate(function() {
  this.ergebnis = new ReactiveVar();
});

Template.berechnung.helpers({
  return Template.instance().ergebnis.get();
});

Template.berechnung.event({
  'submit form': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var eins = parseInt(event.target.ersterWert.value);
    var zwei = parseInt(event.target.zweiterWert.value);
    var ergebnis = eins + zwei;
    console.log(ergebnis);
    template.ergebnis.set(ergebnis);
  }
});
```

Read more about scoped reactivity in Meteor: https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity

Answer (score 0):

You had incorrect closing tag on the div. Also,`ergebnis.value` was not assigned any value according to the Javascript code. Try `ergebnis` alone.

```
<div>{{ergebnis}}</div>
```